# Can I use inside http GET nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

main.js file has

```
app.get('/data/:nodeID/:container', function(req,res) { 
  var container = req.params.container;
  var nodeID = req.params.nodeID;
  api.getLatestContainer(nodeID, container, function(err, data){
    if(err) {return res.send(err);}
    else {return res.send(data); }
  });
});
```

and in same file, I want get data using above code.

```
var nodeID = '010101';
var container = 'ABCD';
setInterval(function() {
    var url = '/data/'+nodeID+'/'+container;
    get_UseAbove(url, function(err, data){
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else console.log(data);
    })
}, 3000);
```

how can I do??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are in the same file, why would you introduce overhead by calling external HTTP call?

you can achieve the same thing but less overhead.

```
app.get('/data/:nodeID/:container', function(req,res) { 
  var container = req.params.container;
  var nodeID = req.params.nodeID;
  api.getLatestContainer(nodeID, container, function(err, data){
    if(err) {return res.send(err);}
    else {return res.send(data); }
  });
});

var nodeID = '010101';
var container = 'ABCD';
setInterval(function() {
    api.getLatestContainer(nodeID, container, function(err, data){
        if(err) {return err;}
        else {return data; }
      });
}, 3000);
```